# Change position of entry title

Tags: loop

I've been unable to move the post entry title to under the post's image. Whenever I do this, the title moves under the content and appears just above the footer.

**loop-single.php -**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post_title">
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
</div><!-- #nav-above -->

<div class="entry-meta">
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</div>

<table id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>
<div class="entry-content-left">
<h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<h2 class="the_subtitle"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></h2>

<div class="entry-content-right">
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Here is [my site](http://tinyurl.com/oukuec8). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the image added in the editor? Or as a featured image?

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding the image directly in the editor, then the_content() will always echo the image. Which means the title can only be above the blog post or below it. You should try adding the image as a featured image. Take a look at this link to see how to add featured image support, and how to use it-> http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Basically you need to add the code below to the functions.php file. This will turn on the featured images option.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

Update the loop to include the featured image.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post_title">
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
</div><!-- #nav-above -->

<div class="entry-meta">
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</div>

<table id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>
<div class="entry-content-left">


<div class="entry-content-right">

<?php  
       //possible image sizes: thumbnail,medium,large,full

       the_post_thumbnail('full');

       <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

       <h2 class="the_subtitle"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></h2>

      the_content(); 

  ?>
```

Go to your blog post edit page, look on the bottom right side for the "Set featured image" box. Add your image.

Comment: Only problem is my featured images are all portrait and some of the images I want to feature on my blog entry are landscape. Also for the most part I use wp galleries to display the images. Could I apply the same function as post thumbnail to the wp gallery?

Comment: I don't think that works with wp gallery because the gallery shortcode is also inside the content editor. If you want to show something before the title it needs to be outside the main content editor. The only other way I can think of doing that is with a plugin. You would need to add a custom image field. I, myself, use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for custom content, but there are other options.

Comment: Hmm... and there's no way to add the gallery to the loop without a plugin?

Comment: There is. do_shortcode() -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

But I don't think that will solve your problem.